# Resizing an image into a banner on photoshop

Tags: resize

I'm resizing an image on photoshop, however, I need to turn an image into a banner. I might be wrong but I need to adjust the canvas size first and then resize the image? I'm new at this as you can tell.

I'm trying to figure out what steps need to be taken.

The dimensions are 940px x 272px - is that the image or canvas size?

Comment: 940px x 272px is your canvas size but it could also be the size of your image. We would need more details on what you're referring to.

Comment: Hi Andrew, my original image is large - 2713px x 1811px. I need to basically resize an image I bought from iStock for a banner to be placed on a web page with the dimensions listed: 940px x 272px. What other details do you need?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to **TRANSFORM** the image. A **CROP** is a completely different compositing operation.

Your *Canvas Size* of *940px x 272px*  is the final size of the web banner to be displayed on the website.Then we are trying to fit the *2713px x 1811px* image inside the *940px x 272px* *Canvas*

If you are in photoshop you can press the shortcut *ctrl+t* while your *2713px x 1811px* image layer is selected to bring it into what is called a **Free Transform**.

From here you can grab a corner and while holding down the **SHIFT** modifer on your keyboard you can proportionally scale the image down to fit element of the photo inside your banner. From here you can make copies of the resized layer, and then you can use the *Rectangle Marquee selection tool* to select portions of the photo. Then use a *Ctrl+J* to make a new layer out of your selection.

Just some guidance to patch together an Web banner from an image.

Hope that helps.

Making copies of the original image

Answer (score 0):

You can change that by either canvas size or by using the crop tool and selecting the specific measurements on the top right corner of the screen

Comment: Thanks, Naty. When I update the canvas size to 940px x 272px, then I'm left with only a portion of the original image. Can I resize the image and recenter it after adjusting the canvas size?

Comment: For that use the crop tool.